# PostAuthenticateAsync in Duende IdentityServer6

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3, idp, duende-identity-server

We have a project that is using IDP version 3. We are trying to upgrade it to Duende IDP6. There are some services missing in IDP6.

e.g.:
IUserService
ITokenService
ILocalization

We do have some class that is inherited from IUserService and override the method "PostAuthenticateLocalAsync". I am not able to locate equivalent service in IDP6.

My question is if i upgrade my project to use IDP6, how can i port my custom logic to IDP6?